# Ionic - Reload and display new data in ng-repeat when clicking back button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-routing, ionic-framework

### Background

I have an `ng-repeat` list that goes to a details page (which has a back button). The `$scope.items` variable is loaded from a get request that occurs when the page is first loaded, with my `refreshItems()` function.

### The Problem

When you click the back button on the details page, you are taken back to the correct page, but the list is **not** refreshed. I need this list to refresh so the new items are loaded and shown.

### Attempted Solution

I thought that I could simply hook up the Back button to an `ng-click` function that uses `ionicHistory` to go back, and then calls my `refreshItems()` function; however, this does not reload the items on the first page.

The above attempt *does* go back to the last page **and** trigger the `refreshItems()` function (and the new data is loaded, which I can see thanks to `console.log()` statements), but I'm guessing the ng-repeat needs to be rebuilt. I found some information on `$scope.$apply()` as well as `$route.reload()` but neither of these fixed the problem when I placed them at the end of my `goBack()` function.

### Code Excerpts

**controller.js**

```
$scope.refreshItems = function() {

    console.log("Refreshing items!");

    $http.get('http://domain/page.aspx').then(function(resp) {
        $scope.items = resp.data; console.log('[Items] Success', resp.data);
    }, function(err) { console.error('ERR', err); });

};


$scope.goBack = function() {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
    $scope.refreshItems();
};
```

**Main Page HTML**

```
<div class="list">

    <a ng-repeat="i in items" class="item" href="#/tab/details?ID={{i.Item_ID}}">
        <b>Item {{i.Item_Name}}</b>
    </a>

</div>
```

**Back Button on Details Page**

```
<ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear" ng-click="goBack();">
        <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

---

### Possible Direction?

I have a `refresher` on the main page which calls `refreshItems()` - and it refreshes them correctly. The problem is most certainly when I try to pair refreshing with either `$ionicHistory.goBack()` or `$state.go()`. Is there a way I can programmatically call the refresher (after/on load), since directly calling the function that refresher is calling is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution for this!

The solution is to use the `$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess')` function. Either check the to/from view with function parameters, or use `$location.path()`:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    console.log("State changed: ", toState);

    if ($location.path() == "/tab/main") {
        $scope.refreshItems();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 29):

Set the cache flag in `ionicConfigProvider`. Disable cache within state provider as follows:

```
$stateProvider.state('mainPage', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/dashboard',
   templateUrl : 'dashboard.html'
})
```

See the [manual](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) for details.

Answer (score 10):

All Ionic views are [cached](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/); prevent caching as follows:

```
cache-view="false"
```

For example:

```
<ion-view view-title="Title" cache-view="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also broadcast an event from the detail page and listen for this event in the listing controller.

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this gets flagged as a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). It helps the community more if you explain your solution and include relevant code snippets.